# Using method merge() of Map<Integer, StringBuilder> to append a String to a StringBuilder(value)

Tags: java

I know that if I have a `Map< Character, Integer>` instead of doing this:

Example_1:

```
int value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    map.put(key, value + 1);
} else {
    map.put(key, 1);
}
```

I can do the same as Example_1 in ONE line.

Example_2:

```
map.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
```

I want to know if is it possible to achieve the same (ONE line statement) with a `Map<Integer,StringBuilder>`.

Example_3:

```
String s = "something";
StringBuilder value = map.get(key);
if (value != null) {
    map.get(key).append(s);
} else {
    map.put(key, new StringBuilder(s));
}
```

So I want to know if there is a more elegant way to express the code in the Example_3 using merge() method or similar.

I tried this but it does not work:

Example_4:

```
map.merge(key, new StringBuilder(s), value.append(s));
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can be had by just running the code that they are asking about and seeing what the behavior/outcome is.

Comment: method merge() or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.computeIfAbsent(“key”, k -> new StringBuilder()).append(s);
```

k -> new StringBuilder() is a lambda function. Here k represents the current key in the map. It is saying, if the map does not contain “key”, then compute a value with this lambda. The lambda accepts a key and returns a value. Since in this case the value does not depend on the value of the key, we just return a new StringBuilder directly. And then we simply append our string s

Comment: Should mention you need to be on java 8+

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: So following the example on the OP this should be:  map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new StringBuilder(s)).append(s);  ? Can you elaborate in the " k -> " part ? Where that "k" comes from ?

Comment: I added an explanation